# VB.NET - Code after Me.Close is executed

Tags: vb.net

Update: Solution by @Mark Hall:
Using Exit Sub after the Me.Close to prevent further execution of the sub while the Closing event is going on..

---

I'm trying to open up a popup window on closing a form where the user can decide if he really wants to close the form.

Therefore I wrote:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True 'Fenster wird nicht geschlossen

    Dim DialogExit As DialogResult
    DialogExit = MsgBox("Do you want to exit the setup process?", vbQuestion Or MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Exit Setup?")

    Select Case DialogExit
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
            Me._Result_ThisForm = Result_Form.Yes
            e.Cancel = False
        Case Else
            'Just no exit
    End Select

End Sub
```

But when I call Me.Close from somewhere in the code, the form just doesn't close but it executes further code!

Like in (somewhere in the code):

```
If bErr = False Then
    Me._Result_ThisForm = Result_Form.Goto_Next ' Just an additional info Enum
    Me.Close()
End If

MsgBox("This should not pop up if bErr = false")
```

-> The "Exit Setup?" MsgBox pops up correctly but the user presses "ok" to exit the programm, the MessageBox from after the "Me.Close()" suddenly appers an then the program closes.

What causes this behavior?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are still running the routine that calls form.close. it is not an immediate stop everything procedure, there are events that still need to be raised. if that is a SubRoutine you are in try calling `Exit Sub` right after the close.

Comment: Thank you, it works with `code`(Exit Sub)! But I heard using Exit Sub is not the best way?

Comment: Your only option if you want to stop your program flow is to use exit sub, or else enclose everything in an IF/Else Statement